# Cloudformation extra when compared with Chef

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-cloudformation

What can I do with Cloudformation that I can not do with chef? It looks like chef support spawning node in the ec2 and I can read back the information of the spawned nodes (ip,..) so why would still need cloudformation for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very little, but what it does makes it worth using.

The primary advantage of CloudFormation is that Amazon ties created resources together. In other words if your application comprises a db, four webservers, an autoscaling group, a launch configuration, ingress rules, some VPC subnets, an internet gateway or two, and a VPN connection, you can manage them in a single place, as a CloudFormation stack. Want to shoot them? That's easy. Kill the stack and *every* resource dies with it.

Sure you could technically do this with Chef and the Amazon API. CloudFormation is little more than a way of generating extremely sophisticated sets of AWS API calls + Magic (tm), so you could always roll your own. Netflix sort of did that with their OS tool, [Asgard](http://techblog.netflix.com/2012/06/asgard-web-based-cloud-management-and.html), and RightScale and other services are more or less that. If those softwares don't meet your needs or if you can't afford them, CloudFormation is a nice supplement to AWS deployments. In fact, you don't even need to rely on it. It's quite simple to [launch chef-solo from CloudFormation](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/IntegratingAWSCloudFormationWithOpscodeChef.pdf), which allows you to leverage the advantages of both.

Comment: Adding a little bit more, Chef is good at managing the capabilities  and behaviors of machines themselves. 


eg - A Chef recipe describes installing packages, patch deployment within machines etc. 

But CloudFormation is about service orchestration. That means, it can define a behavior that consist of multiple AMIs. 

eg - a CloudFormation script can define resource provisioning on top of multiple different services like S3, RDS, EC2 in an orderly, atomically and predictable manner.